What does "fight the enemy where they aren't" mean in the context of "Battleship"?
In the 2012 parody of the board game, the film Battleship has a final battle where Hopper remarks that he finally understands the quote from the Art of War to "fight the enemy where they aren't". Captain Nagata tells him that's not what it means, "not even close". But neither character actually explains what they mean when they say their lines. What did Hopper mean by fighting the enemy where they aren't? Clearly they hit the enemy ship, so...they are fighting the enemy where they are? Is that all Nagata meant when he said the meaning wasn't even close? If not, what did Nagata mean?

Essentially, it means hitting them where they are either weakest, or unprepared. Hitting their supply lines, unsecured towns and forts, and not meeting them in open battle and prepared to face you...but perhaps you missed a following line - "But that's not what it means."

The scene looks like Hopper realizes he just made the aliens fight the USS Missouri where she was not: indeed, mere seconds before, we saw the aliens aim at her extrapolated position. Originally, it possibly advised to set up traps and ambushes in territory not (yet) controlled by the enemy: in which case, not even close indeed.

To be clear you want to understand the writers interpretation of what that phrase means... And not the military application of that phrase.

I believe the film Battleship is an adaptation of the board game, rather than a parody.

@PaulD.Waite - It's honestly that bad a film that it's impossible to tell what they intended

@PaulD.Waite it was a subtle joke about the quality of the film and its resemblance to the actual board game

@Questor yes. I am interested in knowing what Hopper meant, and how his meaning wasn't even close. I believe I understand now that Nagata meant that the actual phrase means what paulie_d says - to hit them at their weakest


What did Hopper mean by fighting the enemy where they aren't?

If memory serves me right, they had to shoot where the alien ship was going to be rather then where it currently was, due to the aliens ships tendency to skip around the water whenever they shot at it.
So in this case I believe harper meant they needed to shoot at where the enemies spaceship was going to be, rather then where it currently was.
As to Nagata. He was just telling Hopper that Hoppers intrepretation of the art of war was innaccurate. as Paul D. Waite put it the phrase

"fighting the enemy where they aren't"

Can be interpreted as:

"Essentially, it means hitting them where they are either weakest, or unprepared. Hitting their supply lines, unsecured towns and forts, and not meeting them in open battle and prepared to face you."

Which is not the same thing as predicting what the enemy is going to do if you do X. And using that to your advantage. That being said the the Art of War advises you to do that as well. (Don't have a quote for it, been a while since I read it).

Memory does not serve you right. The ship that unexpectedly changed course was the Missouri, not the alien ship (which then couldn't correct its shots that were already on the way). So maybe the idea was they used subterfuge instead of following the rule of the game and move only between shots, although that would be a bit meta.
